# Annotation for applying filter in spring-boot to specific url patterns

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-boot

I am developing a spring-boot rest service which contains two filters (implementing the `javax.servlet.Filter` interface). While one filter should apply to all url patterns I want to configure the second filter to only apply to the url pattern `/api/*`.

Currently I am doing this by using following code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        SecurityFilter securityFilter = new SecurityFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(securityFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/*");

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

But my question is if there is an annotation to do the same, considering there are annotations for setting the order of filters (`@Order(..)`). I have tried using `javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter` but spring-boot does seem to ignore this annotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't currently an annotation to do what you want. We do have an [open issue to support `@WebFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2290) which we'd like to fix for Spring Boot 1.3.